# Spring WebMVC I18N - how to support multiple date formats in in- and output

Tags: html, spring, date, spring-mvc

We're using Spring MVC to create a web application and we support, that the users may change their desired locale in the web application. This all works fine and dandy, however we have encountered an issue which doesn't seem to be covered by Spring WebMVC (or we simply don't find the part where it is).

We have several forms that use an  which formats its date to "yyyy-mm-dd" according to the HTML5 specification. On browsers not supporting this we use a polyfill to show a date picker. The date picker formats the date to the locale specific representation e.g. for German "dd.mm.yyyy". Now when the form is sent to us we get it one time as "yyyy-mm-dd" and another time as "dd.mm.yyyy" (and even in more different formats when we support more locales later on). By default Spring MVC seems to be unable to handle this. You can specify a @DateTimeFormat annotation at your form bean but this simply covers one possible format and you cannot add more than one of these annotations.

So we dug a bit deeper and wrote a custom property editor for dates which tries to parse the date in different formats and returns the parsed date once a fitting format has been found. We registered this one in our controller baseclass using an @InitBinder annotation:

```
 @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        String outputFormat = messageSource.getMessage("generic.date.format", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new MultipleDateEditor(outputFormat, ACCEPTED_INPUT_FORMATS));
    }
```

This basically gets the current locale and feeds the property editor with the date format that is suitable for the locale of the current caller. This is actually more work than I expected when using a web framework.

Also there is another problem when the submitted form contains an error and we need to print the parsed date back into the form. We'd like to print the value out with the same format in which we got it. With the property editor we could solve this by remembering internally which format we used to parse the date to use this format again to format the date back into a string. Again, this looks like more work than it should be when using a web framework.

I'd love to hear your solutions to this issue. This is something that is needed in almost every web application supporting multiple languages, so there must be some standardized way or at least a best practise to do so.